# Why ExoPlayer's TimelineQueueNavigator.getMediaDescription method giving wrong index that results in crash due to IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, exoplayer2.x

I was watching a tutorial and but I don't know why the windowIndex parameter  in my case is giving wrong index , sometimes it even gives index of 7 while there are only 3 items in there.
See if you guys can find something .

**Here is the error log -**

```
2022-12-31 14:12:40.844 15041-15041 AndroidRuntime          com.example.spotifyclone             D  Shutting down VM
2022-12-31 14:12:40.861 15041-15041 AndroidRuntime          com.example.spotifyclone             E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.spotifyclone, PID: 15041
                                                                                                    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
                                                                                                        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
                                                                                                        at com.example.spotifyclone.exoplayer.MusicService$MusicQueueNavigator.getMediaDescription(MusicService.kt:120)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.mediasession.TimelineQueueNavigator.publishFloatingQueueWindow(TimelineQueueNavigator.java:207)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.mediasession.TimelineQueueNavigator.onTimelineChanged(TimelineQueueNavigator.java:127)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.mediasession.MediaSessionConnector$ComponentListener.onEvents(MediaSessionConnector.java:1146)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.lambda$new$0$com-google-android-exoplayer2-ExoPlayerImpl(ExoPlayerImpl.java:265)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda11.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.ListenerSet$ListenerHolder.iterationFinished(ListenerSet.java:293)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.ListenerSet.handleMessage(ListenerSet.java:244)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.ListenerSet.$r8$lambda$eEvjP-IE0x3J2lRvKfFbbjRFRvc(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.ListenerSet$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.handleMessage(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
```

**TimelineQueueNavigator Implementation -**

```
private inner class MusicQueueNavigator: TimelineQueueNavigator(mediaSession) {
    override fun getMediaDescription(player: Player, windowIndex: Int): MediaDescriptionCompat {
        return firebaseMusicSource.songs[windowIndex].description
    }
}
```

**And the MusicService file -**

```
private const val SERVICE_TAG = "MusicServiceTag"

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MusicService: MediaBrowserServiceCompat() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dataSourceFactory: DefaultDataSource.Factory

    @Inject
    lateinit var exoPlayer:ExoPlayer

    @Inject
    lateinit var firebaseMusicSource:FirebaseMusicSource

    private val serviceJob = Job()

    // merge properties of our job and main so our custom scope is formed
    private val serviceScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + serviceJob)

    // to cumminicate with service of current music we have music session
    private lateinit var mediaSession:MediaSessionCompat
    private lateinit var mediaSessionConnector:MediaSessionConnector
    private lateinit var musicNotificationManager: MusicNotificationManager

    private lateinit var musicPlayerEventListener:MusicPlayerEventListener

    var isforegroundService = false
    private var curPlayingSong: MediaMetadataCompat? = null

    private var isPlayerPrepared = false

    companion object{
        var curSongDuration = 0L
        private set
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        serviceScope.launch {
            firebaseMusicSource.fetchMediaData()
        }

        //to do something on notification click we have this intent
        val activityIntent = packageManager?.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)?.let {
            if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S ) PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, it, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
            else PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, it, 0 )
        }

        mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(this, SERVICE_TAG).apply {
            setSessionActivity(activityIntent)
            isActive = true
        }

        /* service extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat and it contains the sessionToken property
        that can be used to get info about specific different music session using different tokens */
        sessionToken = mediaSession.sessionToken

        musicNotificationManager = MusicNotificationManager(
            context= this,
            sessionToken = mediaSession.sessionToken,
            notificationListener= MusicPlayerNotificationListener(this),
            newSongCallbacks= {
                curSongDuration = exoPlayer.duration
            }
        )

        val musicPlaybackPreparer:MusicPlaybackPreparer = MusicPlaybackPreparer(firebaseMusicSource){
            curPlayingSong = it
            preparePlayer(
                firebaseMusicSource.songs,
                it,
                true
            )
            Log.d("MUSICSERVICE", "Player Playback prepared and also player prepared ")
        }

        mediaSessionConnector = MediaSessionConnector(mediaSession)
        mediaSessionConnector.setPlaybackPreparer(musicPlaybackPreparer)
        mediaSessionConnector.setPlayer(exoPlayer)
        mediaSessionConnector.setQueueNavigator(MusicQueueNavigator())

        musicPlayerEventListener = MusicPlayerEventListener(this)
        exoPlayer.addListener(musicPlayerEventListener)
        musicNotificationManager.showNotification(exoPlayer)
    }

    private inner class MusicQueueNavigator: TimelineQueueNavigator(mediaSession) {
        override fun getMediaDescription(player: Player, windowIndex: Int): MediaDescriptionCompat {
            return firebaseMusicSource.songs[windowIndex].description 
        }
    }

    private fun preparePlayer(
        songs:List<MediaMetadataCompat>,
        itemToPlay:MediaMetadataCompat?,
        playNow: Boolean
    ){
        val curSongIndex = if(curPlayingSong == null) 0 else songs.indexOf(itemToPlay)

        exoPlayer.prepare()
        exoPlayer.addMediaSource(firebaseMusicSource.asMediaSource(dataSourceFactory))
        exoPlayer.seekTo(curSongIndex,0L)
        exoPlayer.playWhenReady =  playNow
        Log.d("MUSICSERVICE", "Player prepared ")
    }

    override fun onGetRoot(
        clientPackageName: String,
        clientUid: Int,
        rootHints: Bundle?
    ): BrowserRoot? {

        return BrowserRoot(MEDIA_ROOT_ID, null)

    }

    override fun onLoadChildren(
        parentId: String,
        result: Result<MutableList<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>>
    ) {
        when(parentId){

            MEDIA_ROOT_ID -> {
                val resultSent:Boolean = firebaseMusicSource.whenReady { isInitialized ->
                    if(isInitialized){
                        result.sendResult(firebaseMusicSource.asMediaItem())
                        if(!isPlayerPrepared && firebaseMusicSource.songs.isEmpty()){
                            preparePlayer( firebaseMusicSource.songs, firebaseMusicSource.songs[0], false )
                            isPlayerPrepared = true
                            Log.d("MUSICSERVICE", "Player prepared during loadChildren ")
                        }
                    }else{
                        mediaSession.sendSessionEvent(NETWORK_ERROR, null)
                        result.sendResult(null)

                    }
                }

                if(!resultSent){
                    // wait for some time to get results ready and call the whole
                    // loading thing after some time
                    result.detach()
                }

            }

        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        serviceScope.cancel()

        exoPlayer.release()
        exoPlayer.removeListener(musicPlayerEventListener)
    }

    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
        exoPlayer.stop()
    }

}
```

**Here is complete logcat stack trace : [Stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/smartphonecodes1/0dee0302a2ecee85f60a23e4bc820422)**

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo actually whenever i click on new song while a song is already playing the app crashes because in MusicService's MusicQueueNavigator the getMediaDescription() should return the respective song's description using windowIndex parameter but it throws the IndexOutOfBondException while it should give correct index so song can be changed without any crash

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo added the complete logcats stacktrace

Comment: You have an IndexOutOfBoundsException. At which particular line of code does it occur?

Comment: Exception is Inside MusicService > inner class MusicQueueNavigator > getMediaDescription's return statement i.e. - ( return firebaseMusicSource.songs[windowIndex].description ) , you can see complete implementation of MusicQueueNavigator in above code snippet